# How to toggle a 3D flip in knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

This is probably just to stupid, but I can´t seem to think straight.

I have this  I want to flip (see http://jsfiddle.net/3Z2KG/1/).
I want to flip it with a button.

```
ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.flipIt = function() {
        //alert("At least this is working!");
        $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped').click(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('flipped');
        });
        return false;
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

I´ve tried .toggleClass('flipped') as well.
However I´m not getting the reaction I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into two problems. First, `this` is the wrong value in your `flipIt()` function. In knockout, functions called by click bindings are passed two arguments, the data and the event object for the actual click event. You need to pass those to your function like:

```
self.flipIt = function(data, event) {
```

Then, in place of `this`, you can use the `event.target` property to access the actual DOM element that fired the click event.

Your second issue is with your jQuery selector to find the actual `.card` element. The `find` method searches for descendants of an element, but the `.card` element is actually a child of the `<button>`'s sibling, so you need something more like this:

```
$(event.target).siblings().find(".card").toggleClass('flipped');
```

I also removed the second click handler, since we can take care of removing the class by using jQuery's `toggleClass` method instead.

I updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3Z2KG/2/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot Adrien. I tried this in my code (not the fiddle) and it didm´t work. However your siblings-issue put me on track and in my code I had to exchange siblings() with parents. Now it works. :)

Answer (score 3):

You're making things more complicated than they need to be by adding actual orchestration to the `flipIt` click function. My suggestion is to keep things discrete and disjoint by using an intermediate observable to track the flipped state.

Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/B5TtB/1/ for more information. Here's the highlights of what I'm suggesting:

- Add a `flipped()` observable to the view model: `self.flipped = ko.observable(false);`
- Add a `css` binding to the card div: `<div class="card" data-bind="css: { flipped: flipped() }">`
- In your `flipIt` function, simply set the value of the observable to its boolean inverse:

  `var flipped = self.flipped();`
  `self.flipped(!flipped);`

This will toggle the class on click. Admittedly, I'm not able to get the other stuff to work (probably because I'm not on a webkit browser), but maybe that will get you started.

Comment: @Asle G, use the solution without jQuery. this is the clean way of doing this. The whole point of using ko is to not have jQ mish mash all over the place

Comment: Brilliant. Beautiful. Your solution makes me believe in mankind again! :)
Thanx a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it: http://jsfiddle.net/69vTt/7/

Sample template:

```
<button data-bind="click: toggleFlip">Flip</button>
<div data-bind="css: { 'flipOutY' : isFlipped, 'flipInY': !isFlipped() }" class="animated">
    <h1>Some lovely title</h1>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
```

Sample view model:

```
function vm(){
    this.isFlipped = ko.observable(false);
    this.toggleFlip = function(){
        this.isFlipped(!this.isFlipped());
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

And flipping CSS:

```
.animated {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flipInY {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(-10deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(-10deg);
  }

  70% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(10deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(10deg);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes flipInY {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }

  40% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(-10deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(-10deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(-10deg);
  }

  70% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(10deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(10deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(10deg);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.flipInY {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  -ms-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  backface-visibility: visible !important;
  -webkit-animation-name: flipInY;
  animation-name: flipInY;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flipOutY {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes flipOutY {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.flipOutY {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  -ms-backface-visibility: visible !important;
  backface-visibility: visible !important;
  -webkit-animation-name: flipOutY;
  animation-name: flipOutY;
}
```

Comment: Lovely! I like the bounce effect there. Bu where do you put the "back" side of the card in the html?